# Using wildcard with 'ls'

Tags: linux, unix, ls

I want to list the all files having a name like these:

```
12.0.3.1_CA
12.0.3.2A_CA
12.0.3.2B_CA
```

I tried

```
ls -ltr 12.0.3.?*_CA
```

That worked, but fails when I have files like:

```
12.0.3.2AA_CA
12.0.3.2A2_CA
```

Comment: Use regex  example `ls | egrep 'regex_expression'`

Comment: Looking for something like this - `ls 12.0.3.*_CA`
Please expand problem description for correct responses.

Comment: I want to list the files i mentioned above by using 'ls' command . "ls 12.0.3.*_CA" will not work for me because it will list all files which are having filename like 12.0.3.123_CA or 12.0.3.1A but i dont want this . After "12.0.3." I can two characters max (there can be one character also ) then _CA .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one character at max after the '?' then try:

```
ls -ltr 12.0.3.?[*]_CA
```

[] is used to encase any character you want, like if we want to have 'ac' in the name we would use [ac].